# Implicitly-typed variables must be initialized

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Task2
{
    class BirthDate
    {
        static void Main(string[] date)
        {
            var Month;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your month of birth:");
            Month = Console.ReadLine();

            var Day;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your day of birth:");
            Day = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Your birth month is {0}, on day {1}", Month, Day);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to compile, I get two errors from the variables and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Use `String`, it's easier for everyone. It's a strongly typed language, so strong-type your variables plz.

Answer (score 3):

When you put just

```
 var Day;
```

the compiler can't *figure out* `Day` variable's *actual type*; change it to

```
 var Day = Console.ReadLine();
```

and having known that `Console.ReadLine()` returns `String`, the compiler can easily detect that `Day` is of type `String`:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Please enter your month of birth:");
 var Month = Console.ReadLine();

 Console.WriteLine("Please enter your day of birth:");
 var Day = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use implicitly typed variable without initialization. You should initialize the variabe to let compiler to infer type of variable.

Don't use inplicitly typed variables when type of variable not obvious when looking on code.

```
var iDontKnowWhatTypeOfIt = SomeMethod();  // not good

var itIsObviousThatImTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't define which type Month and Day are.
when using "var" you have to set a value to it upon definition.
the easiest way to fix your code is to simply write var before the console read as such:

```
using System;

namespace Task2
{
    class BirthDate
    {
       static void Main(string[] date)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Please enter your month of birth:");
           var Month = Console.ReadLine();
           Console.WriteLine("Please enter your day of birth:");
           var Day = Console.ReadLine();
           Console.WriteLine("Your birth month is {0}, on day {1}", Month, Day);
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either let compiler infer the type from assignment

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your month of birth:");
var Month = Console.ReadLine();
```

Or specify the type explicitly

```
string Month;
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your month of birth:");
Month = Console.ReadLine();
```